# Symfony 2- it looks like your system doesn't support relative symbolic links

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in symfony 2. I just started install symfony 2.7 on windows 7.
I downloaded Composer and run as in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

But when I run command,

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

and set all parametters like database_host, database_name,.... as default and hit enter some error happened:

```
    Trying to install assets as symbolic links.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
It looks like your system doesn't support relative symbolic links, so the assets
 were installed by using absolute symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodi
stribution
It looks like your system doesn't support relative symbolic links, so the assets
 were installed by using absolute symbolic links.
```

My Symfony is still running but there are many errors.
there are many file is missing in my 'my_project_name\src\AppBundle' folder than folder in tutorial. And many error 'No route found for "GET /" 'when run '127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/'; in browser
Can anyone help me fix this
My php version is 5.5.12

Comment: "there are many errors" What sort of errors?

Comment: there are many file is missing in my 'my_project_name\src\AppBundle' folder than folder in tutorial. And many error 'No route found for "GET /" 'when run 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/' in browser

Answer (score 9):

You need to run composer as administrator (of Windows). Then it will create symbolic links.

Also you can change method for default assets management after any `composer update` or `composer install` by changing in `composer.json` next line:

```
"symfony-assets-install": "relative",
```

to this:

```
"symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
```

or this:

```
"symfony-assets-install": "hard-copy",
```

Comment: thank you, @Michael Sivolobov , but it doesn't work, I ran cmd as administrator

Comment: Are you sure? You can be logged in as administrator but your cmd will be ran without any privileges. You need to manually choose Run as Administrator from context menu on the app.

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I have just tried it again by 'Run as Administrator', but It still does not work. Are there any softwares to setup to have relative symbolic links?

Comment: This is core functionality of your OS (Windows) it doesn't need any other software. As you can see here: http://superuser.com/questions/361826/how-do-you-make-a-symbolic-link-with-a-relative-path-using-mklink it is possible on windows.

Comment: thank you very much, I have just install symfony 2.3.30, and it run successfully immediately with no error, I think the problem is in symfony 2.7

Comment: The problem is about `relative` symlinks that are set by default in Symfony 2.7. I updated my answer to change this behavior.

Comment: It still not work, your mean is changing composer.json in my_project_name folder then run 'composer update' and then reinstall symfony 2.7?

Comment: It is strange behavior if you use `"symfony-assets-install": "symlink"` but it tries install it as `relative`. Maybe you have another error? Or have some opcode cache enabled for CLI?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an OS which supports symlinks (linux, OS X, and I guess all OS but Windows), you can install the assets calling (I don't exactly remember the call, the important thing here is the symlink option):

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

This way, instead of having a copy of each bundle's resources, you'll have a symlink, so there should be no need to update. If you have an OS which doesn't support symlinks, I think you'll have to keep updating or reinstalling assets (in fact, I always used assets:install, I didn't knew there was an update option :P).

Comment: OP has problem while executing command from your answer. He needs solution to solve this problem.